# C# How to read “dc:creator” element from an RSS feed?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am trying read field “dc:creator” in C# (Windows Universal App) and not work. I need help. Please

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var rssContent = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.talkingwindows.com.br/feed");
XElement xmlitems = XElement.Parse(rssContent);
List<XElement> elements = xmlitems.Descendants("item").ToList();

foreach (XElement rss in elements)
{
    Lista.Add(
        new Model
        {
          Titulo = rss.Element("title").Value,
          DataPublicacao = rss.Element("pubDate").Value,
          Descricao = rss.Element("description").Value,
          //Autor = rss.Element("dc:creator xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\"").Value,
          Link = rss.Element("link").Value
        }
     );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the element in a specific namespace, you need to prefix it with an `XNamespace`. In your case, it should look like this:

```
XNamespace dcNamespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";

foreach (XElement rss in elements)
{
    Lista.Add(
        new Model
        {
            Titulo = rss.Element("title").Value,
            DataPublicacao = rss.Element("pubDate").Value,
            Descricao = rss.Element("description").Value,
            Autor = rss.Element(dcNamespace + "creator").Value,
            Link = rss.Element("link").Value
        }
    );
}
```

Or if you prefer, you can do it like this:

```
Autor = rss.Element("{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}creator").Value,
```

Further reading on this can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Windows.Web.Syndication` is an API for parsing RSS and Atom feeds. There is a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/syndication/cs).

In that case, you can find extension elements as `dc:creator` in `SyndicationItem.ElementExtensions`.

Answer (score 0):

## Dotnet Core Answer

Reading RSS Feeds using `SyndicationClass` takes just a couple of lines of code

#### Install Package: System.ServiceModel.Syndication

```
 using System.Xml;
 using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;

 var reader = XmlReader.Create("https://blogs.yourdomain.com/feed");
 var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load<SyndicationFeed>(reader);

 foreach (var blog in feed.Items)
 var creator = blog.ElementExtensions.First(x => x.OuterName == "creator").GetObject<string>();
```